How to handle vulnerability Cx78f40514-81ff in dependencies that rely on commons-collections?
My project relies on several dependencies that transitively depend on Apache Commons Collections 3.2.2. IntelliJ warns me about a CVE in this library, which curiously is not visible on maven repository. For example Apache Commons BeanUtils 1.9.4, despite being on the last available version still uses that old version of commons-collections, which apparently has this annoying CVE. And a LOT of librairies use beanutils
Now, if I want to get rid of this CVE, how to proceed? I already pushed every dependency I could to the last available one and even used DependenciesManagement to handle the versions of transitive dependencies. But as for commons-collections, they changed their pakcages to commons-collections4 starting with the 4.0 version so it is quite troublesome to exclude/update dependencies in this case.
Maybe bridging proxy from commons-collections to commons-collections4 would do the trick. I can't think of anything else what do you think?

I don’t understand why this is considered “high”. The description reads as if this action would always break, so it’s very unlikely that any application is ever performing this action. It’s hard to imagine how an attacker could make an application add a collection to itself when it didn’t do this in the first place.

Note that similar problems exist with all standard Java collections: if you add it to itself and then call the hashcode() on the collection the code will crash with a StackOverflowException (i.e. Collection<Object> x = new ArrayList<>(); x.add(x); x.hashcode();. Not really a problem in real production code because normally a collection is not added to itself.

Why do you say that is "troublesome to exclude/update dependencies"? Excluding dependencies is the way to go.

@ClaudioWeiler if you exclude depenencies that are required by the code you get errors, right? Unless you have  provided a replacement with same package. For example you can exclude log4J and replace it by log4J-over-slf4J. Or else you have to be sure that the code you call in your direct dependencies does not call the transitive dependencies that you want to exclude

You say that you already included dependency on collections4, so just exclude transitive dependencies. Still can't understand what you mean. Can you share a minimum reproducible example?

First, include direct dependency.
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
      <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>

Now you need to exclude transitive dependency from all of your direct dependencies that depends on commons-collections.
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>{dependency-group}</groupId>
      <artifactId>{dependency-artifact}</artifactId>
      <version>{dependency-version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>


Let's say I use beanutils, which relies on commons-collections.
In the code of beanUtils, there is a place where it uses import org.apache.commons.collections.FastHashMap. Now in the library commons-collections4, the FastHashMap object does not exist anymore. So how do you think your solution can work?

@Aldian this solution can't correct differences between libraries version, like inclusion/exclusion of classes or changes in package names. This solution is for overriding maven packages name/version that can be override.

so this is not a solution for my initial problem: handling vulnerability Cx78f40514-81ff in dependencies that rely on commons-collections. As a consequence I can't accept your answer

Sure @Aldian . But I would say that you need to review all your question. Now, your problem isn't the presence of CVE, but a problem with dependencies that suffer on breaking changes.
